# Detecting Outgoing SOAP Envelope

Tags: c#, web-services, .net-4.0

I am using third party web service and trying to log the outgoing SOAP envelop when the web service method is called.

Came across this article about [How to capture SOAP envelopes when consuming a web service in ASP.NET.](http://blog.encoresystems.net/articles/how-to-capture-soap-envelopes-when-consuming-a-web-service.aspx) and implemented similar way. B

But for some reason `ProcessMessage` is not get called.

My class and namespace looks like below

```
namespace MyServiceClient
{
    public class MySeriviceSoap : SoapExtension
    {
     ......
```

And my `app.config`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>

  <system.web>
    <webServices>
      <soapExtensionTypes>
        <add type="MyServiceClient.MySeriviceSoap, MyServiceClient, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" priority="1" />
      </soapExtensionTypes>
    </webServices>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Any help on this please

Answer (score 1):

The `type` attribute requires a fully qualified type name. This is explained in [MSDN: `<add>` Element for `<soapExtensionTypes>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8f7skt4f(v=vs.85).aspx):

> **type** Specifies the SOAP extension class to add. The type attribute value must be on one line, and include the fully qualified type name. When the assembly is placed in the Global Assembly Cache (GAC), it must also include the version, culture and public key token of the signed assembly.

A "fully qualified type name" is in a format like `Namespace.TypeName[, AssemblyName][, Version][, Culture][, Token]`.

So you need something like this:

```
 <add type="MyServiceClient.MySeriviceSoap, YourAssemblyName" priority="1" />
```

See also [MSDN: Specifying Fully Qualified Type Names](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yfsftwz6(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Great! Will try this out

Comment: Tried using fully qualified type name, but having the same result. I have updated the question with new code

Comment: Oh, this is for Web Services (ASMX)... chances are you have a WCF client. Update your question with what client you're using.

Comment: It something been already implemented using web service (wsdl)

Comment: You don't seem to understand what I'm asking. Is the **client** generated through ASMX (wsdl.exe, Add Web Service Reference) or through WCF (svcutil.exe, Add Service Reference)?

Comment: Oh sorry, its been added as "Add Web Service Reference"